# Publishing Website Using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a website hh-alrawi.com, the problem is every time I publish the site the main page (Index.aspx) does not appear, the correct site URL is : http://www.hh-alrawi.com/index.aspx , so I wonder how can i put the main page name after the domain name (Index.aspx) always after the URL, I tried to edit my web config but it's not working, my Web Config :

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>

    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>

    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>

    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Index.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Index.aspx" />
    </customErrors>

  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>

    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <add value="Index.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>

  </system.webServer>    

</configuration>
```

Please check the site to understand what i say :), Thnx for your time

Answer (score 0):

Publish your website using VS and save it onto the file system. My hosting hostgator has the option of uploading zip files, if your does too, then zip the files produced and upload the zip/rar produced in your website's root folder or individually upload all files. Tell me if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Index file appears wherever you put it.if you put it just under your www directory it will automatically displayed when you visit your website.